# How do I get a full error response with Angular 4?

Tags: angular

I am making an http request with Angular HttpClient.

```
http.get(`${hostUrl}/myproject/infrastructure-status`)
.subscribe(
(resp) => {
  // handle response
},
(error) => {
 console.log(error)
});
```

In my console, an error of type HttpErrorResponse is logged:
[image: Error logged on console]

However, the backend response on my network tab is not the same:

[image: Headers error network tab]

[image]

Can I get the full error response in Angular? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

The error you get is also a response object so if you cast it to response you can read the body.
For me this works:

```
http.get(`${hostUrl}/myproject/infrastructure-status`)
           .subscribe(
           (resp) => {
              // handle response
           },
           (error) => {
              if (error instanceof Response) {
                 console.log(error.text());
              }
           });
```

What seems strange to me is that you get a ProgressEventObject. I always get a Response object that includes the body also. Maybe the difference is that the response in your case is HTML I was testing with calling a WebApi that returns JSON.

Comment: ProgressEvent is obtainable by flag.